# Сделать репост в Instagram с wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Добрый день, помогите сделать ссылку share в instagram.
Для facebook & twitter легко сделать пример вот:

```
Facebook
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="blank"><i class="i-fb"></i></a>
Twitter
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo urlencode( get_the_title() ) ?>&amp;url=<?php echo urlencode( get_permalink() ); ?>" target="blank"><i class="i-tw"></i></a>
```

А как сделать подобное для instagram?

Comment: Судя по тому, что ни в одном из агрегаторов социалок нет возможности добавить расшаривание в instagram, то, скорее всего, никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инстаграмм примерно год назад закрыл доступ к своему API для расшаривания фоток. Вот как они это объяснили:

At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:

Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.